# how to simply handle the request with python

Tags: python, html, testing, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to do some testing in html5 uploading files,here is the simple html codes:

```
var fileInput=document.getElementById("the-file")

fileInput.addEventListener('change',function(e){

var file=e.target.files[0]

var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.open('post','upload/handlecode',true)

xhr.send(file)
}
```

I use 
`python -m SimpleHTTPServer` 
to test this section
the problem is that I DON'T know how to write the **handlecode** file to handle
the http request,

the **handlecode** file only save the file in the upload floder,no more complicated tasks

Although I don'k know whether testing in this way is right or not

Can someone give some hints
or offer me the right way to test ,Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/):

```
from bottle import request, route, run

@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    data = request.files.get('data')
    raw = data.file.read()
    filename = data.filename
    return "You uploaded %s (%d bytes)." % (filename, len(raw))

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```